# Custom Logo Problems

Tags: magento-1.9

I have tried to change the default logo but I get greeted with the small blue box with a question mark in. I have uploaded it to the right place and I have changed the design option in Config but it won't have any. I have tried it again with the default logo and it works fine, just not with custom logos. Its a PNG if that helps, but I read that it doesn't matter what the format whether it be PNG or GIF.

Thanks,

Comment: If your problem was solved, please select one of the answers as "accepted" to mark this question as solved. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem now. I was changing the logo in the directory /skin/frontend/default/images not /skin/frontend/rwd/images (Where the logo actually is if you are using the default theme like me). There is a logo.gif file in each of these which lead me to believe it was there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure your logo in System - Configuration - Design (images/yourlogo.png)
2. Put your logo per FTP in skin/frontend/{{yourpackage}}/{{yourtheme}}/images/yourlogo.png
3. Refresh the cache.

Comment: This is exactly what I have done but no success. I have tried it with other images too but still no success. Thanks

Comment: then you are doing something wrong...

Answer (score 0):

It will need some config (not just in the backend) to use a logo file that name is not "logo.png" , so easiest way is to name your file "logo.png" and replace it with the orginal one.

Comment: I have tried this but no success. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I usually just replace the logo.gif, logo_email.gif, and logo_print.gif in my skin/frontend/default/{mytheme}/images/ folder.